# Printer works only after changing static ip and reboot

Tags: networking, printer

I have this setup, X-Lable printer and X-cutting machine.

X-Printer network settings :

```
Sub net : 255.255.255.0 
IP: 172.24.15.90
```

X-Cutting machine :

```
Sub net: 255.255.255.0
IP: 172.24.15.110
```

Both set to static reserved IP, Both connected to a switch, which is connected to local network.

Problem : Printer stops to print.

Solution : I have to change IP of the X-printer to .91, then reboot all. Next day switch back to .90, and repeat...

Could you please suggest how to trouble shoot this problem ?

Comment: You say you have "static reserved IP"... which one do you have... "static IP" (in most cases) is where you configure the device's IP on the device (or through it's software) and "reserved" means you use a DHCP server and you have told it to reserve an IP for the device's MAC address so that it always gets the same address... If you have set a static IP and you have a DHCP server then you must make sure you put the static IP outside the DHCP pool scope so that it cannot issue the same IP to another device (IP conflict).

Comment: Further to Chris's comment, try this. When the problem happens, switch off the printer, and then see if you can still ping it from the PC. If you can, you have a duplicate IP address, and need to change the DHCP ad dress pool.

Comment: @hdhondt will try.

Comment: @BigChris 90 was reserved, 91 was part of dhcp pool. but 90 was already assigned to a laptop, that was not always on the network. Problem fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have another device also using .90 - perhaps it is part of a DHCP pool or a misconfigured device.

You can check this by comparing the MAC address reported by `arp -a` for .90 when the printer is working vs when not.

Comment: What a gr8 command. I  Will try this.

Comment: Sorry i am late to say this, but the ip address was the same on some guys laptop, he did set it manually. Its solved now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add BOOTP options to your router https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_Protocol
2. Check if you have Layer3 Switch with MAC blocking mode and turn it of on the port.

In general it will solve 90% problems with older printers and similar hardware.

Comment: I don't have access to the router or a switch inside my company. That will be a new problem on its own :) But will try this, thanks !